# How to separate numbers from a given word using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I need to separate given words if they are surrounding by numbers. For example the word is "x".

```
s = '''
1x 3    # OK
s1x2    # WRONG
2x      # OK
s1 x2   # WRONG
x2      # OK
1sx3    # WRONG
'''

print(re.sub("(?<=\d)\s*x\s*(?=\d)", " x ", s))
```

This separates everything even if surrounding number is not a number, I mean, `s1 x2` nor `s1x3x` should not be matched.

On the other hand it doesn't work for "no" - only for the last 2 rows:

```
s = '''
2 no 3  # OK (but it's not needed to match)
2no     # OK
3no2    # OK
no9     # OK
xno9    # WRONG
5 non   # WRONG (for 'no')
'''

print(re.sub("(?<=\d)\s*no\s*(?=\d)", " x ", s))
```

I've edited examples a bit.
There's a need to use it within a sentence, for example:

> Sever land and erect 1x 3 Bedroom chalet bungalow and 1x2 bedroom
>   bungalow. Installation of 2 non-illuminated fascia signs and 2no ad
>   signs.

Both from 1st sentence should match, only second from 2nd sentence.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the below post I've found this to match:

```
\b(?:\d*\s*x\s*\d+|\d+\s*x\s*\d*)\b
```

but the problem is it doesn't work for replacement. The idea is to add for surrounded words by numbers an extra space. So while this now pattern selects properly those phrases (both from single row and sentences) it doesn't work with replacement because it should match only those words:

```
s = "Sever land and erect 1x 3 Bedroom chalet bungalow and 1x2 Bedroom bungalow"

re.sub("\b(?:\d*\s*x\s*\d+|\d+\s*x\s*\d*)\b", " x ", s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: So you mean like `\b\d+\s*(x)\s*\d+\b` https://regex101.com/r/yaWKvl/1

Comment: _This separates everything even if surrounding number is not a number_ What do you mean by "surrounding number is not a number"?

Comment: Surrounded by numbers, does that mean it could also be just 1 number?

Comment: I assume `2` is a number while `s2` or `2s1` not, but they include numbers so are not just alphabetic words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = '''
Sever land and erect 1x 3 Bedroom chalet bungalow and 1x2 bedroom bungalow. Installation of 2 non-illuminated fascia signs and 2no ad signs.
'''

cases = ['no', 'nos', 'x']

import re

l = data
for case in cases:
    l = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', re.sub(r'(?<=\d| ){}(?=\d| )'.format(case), r' {} '.format(case), l))

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
Sever land and erect 1 x 3 Bedroom chalet bungalow and 1 x 2 bedroom bungalow. Installation of 2 non-illuminated fascia signs and 2 no ad signs.
```

Comment: I need to match each separately even if they are within sentence (please look the bottom of my post)

Comment: Great, this seem to work but what is this part for (`r'\s{2,}'`)? How to add this to a loop for list of many words?

Comment: Why 'x' not in the list? What if the 'x' is not in the sentence? If data is only second sentence I get `Installation of 2 non-illuminated fascia signs and 2 x ad signs.`

Comment: Nope. `2no` should get extra space and become `2 no`. This `x` is not any special case so your solution just overfits towards it.

Comment: @Peter.k Ok, then I misunderstood. Check my new answer.

Comment: @Andrey thanks for your effort and sorry for being so confusing. I started this post very badly.

Answer (score 1):

You might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) using `|` to match a required digit at either side where `x` or `n`o could be matched in the middle.

```
^(?:\d* *(?:x|no)\s*\d+|\d+\s*(?:x|no) *\d*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eo8WeV/1)

Comment: You are close. Please try make it work for `x2` or `2x`.

Comment: @Peter.k Do you mean like `^(?:\d*\s*x\s*\d+|\d+\s*x\s*\d*)$`  https://regex101.com/r/yaWKvl/2

Comment: @Peter.k Or with `x` and `no` https://regex101.com/r/yaWKvl/3

Comment: Yes, it works for those examples. Please let me run it thru all cases because maybe I missed something.

Comment: Single version is ok because I run it in loop.

Comment: I cannot use `^` and `$` because many matches are within sentences.

Comment: @Peter.k Not the most perfomant pattern, but taking all those cases into account you might first match what you don't want and then capture what you do want in a capturing group https://regex101.com/r/rMxdJ9/1 This could be error prone and perhaps hard to maintain.